# How to solve Lotka-Volterra with periodic coefficients differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

I would like to ask which transformation should I use to recive from this Lotka-Volterra inequality
$$x'=x(a-bx-cy)<x(a-bx)$$
this differential form
$$x(t)\leq \frac{x(T)e^{A(t)}}{1+x(T)\int_{T}^{t}e^{A(s)}b(s)ds}, \text{where} A(t)=\int_{T}^{t}a(s)ds.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by $x^2$ to get a linear differential inequality
$$
-(x^{-1})'\le ax^{-1}-b,
$$
Apply the integrating factor $e^{A(t)}$ where $A'(t)=a(t)$
$$
be^{A(t)}\le (e^{A(t)}x^{-1})'
$$
integrate on both sides over $[T,t]$, then solve for $x(t)$.